# How to put div aside div when first has no fixed length

Tags: html, css

I am trying to put two divs one aside another like

```
.left_sender {
    width: 150px;
    float: left;
}

.left_message {
    margin-left: 150px;
}

<div class="left_sender"></div><div class="left_message"></div>
```

and it works but problem is when content in first div (with class **left_sender**) is short there is lot off blank space. How to change this to wrap only necessary width (like **wrap_content** in android) but still to be one aside another ?

http://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=HdszR2skuP

Comment: try add it to a jsfiddle or something. it will make it so much more easy for us to see what you mean

Comment: you can use max-width/min-width.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok just after a little work on the fiddle what you need is : not declare a fixed `width` or set it to `auto` to make the container fit the content:

```
.left_sender {
   width:auto;
}
```

And to take the other div at the side add `float` :

```
.left_message { 
  float:left;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Give .left_sender a `max-width` instead of a `width`:

```
.left_sender {
    max-width: 150px;
    float: left;
}
```